# Development server giving an error in React: TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined

Tags: reactjs

I am getting an error after running my React development server a few times, previously I run this project didn't get an error like this, after a few months restarting this project I am getting an error like this. How can I solve this error?

```js
TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:122:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:375:7)
    at noopServiceWorkerMiddleware (C:\xampp\htdocs\wms-react-template\node_modules\react-dev-utils\noopServiceWorkerMiddleware.js:14:26)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\wms-react-template\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\xampp\htdocs\wms-react-template\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at C:\xampp\htdocs\wms-react-template\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\xampp\htdocs\wms-react-template\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\xampp\htdocs\wms-react-template\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at launchEditorMiddleware (C:\xampp\htdocs\wms-react-template\node_modules\react-dev-utils\errorOverlayMiddleware.js:20:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\xampp\htdocs\wms-react-template\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
```

Comment: Well the error is pretty self-explanatory. You're passing `undefined` to a call to the path module. Need to determine why it's being passed undefined and fix that, and probably add a check to that function so if it happens you won't go ahead with the path call and cause a crash

Comment: After Migrating from 4.0.0 to 4.0.1                                                                                                           npm install --save --save-exact react-scripts@4.0.1                                                                         This error solved.

Comment: Hmm weird, cos `react-scripts` is for front end code, and this was a Node issue lol. Oh well, if the problem's fixed! :D